# Python File Generator in Perl

Tags: python, perl, iterator, generator

Hello everybody is it possible to create in perl an file generator like the conecpt in python.

Actuall i have the following code snippet to read chunks from an file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub getChunck {
    my $file = shift;
    my @chunck;
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Unable to open '$file': $!";
    while(<$fh>) {
        push @chunck, $_;
        push @chunck, "\n" unless $. % 4;
    }
    return @chunck;
}

my @chunck = getChunck('DUMP');
```

I read the hole file in chunks into an array.
But i want to know if it is possible to read an chunk or data from file and then process it (like in python with yield).

I hope someone could help me to create an "yield" function in perl.
I know there are some libs to work with generators in perl, but i dont want to include an lib. (maybe it is not possible?)

Thanks to everybody.

Maybe it could works so:

```
- open file and read line for line
- yield line
- process the line with another function.
```

Thanks.

Comment: See also [What is the Perl version of a Python iterator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3775413/2173773)

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland for your answer. I will take a look at the links